# How can I compile three files together?

Tags: c++, g++

I have three files: **class.h** with declaration of class; **class.cpp** with definition of class and **main.cpp** where I call class. How can I compile it?

I've tried

```
g++ main.cpp class.h class.cpp
```

but I have a lot of errors like "not declared in this copy or library doesn't include", but I actually included this libraries in class.h and inclued class.h in main.cpp. I mean when I compile it in Visual Studio all is working, but in Linux it isn't.

Comment: Compiling the header file will create a pre-compiled header, which might not be what you want to do. Files that use things referenced in the header file need to `#include "class.h"`. Then, just compile those files. `g++ main.cpp class.cpp` might be enough.